# Could there be something significant or prophetic about the way Jericho was attacked & destroyed in Joshua 6?

Tags: joshua

(KJV) Joshua 6

> 1 Now Jericho was straitly shut up because of the children of Israel:  none went out, and none came in.   2 And the LORD said unto Joshua, See, I have given into thine hand Jericho, and the king thereof, and the mighty men of valour.   3 And ye shall compass the city, all ye men of war, and go round about the city once.   Thus shalt thou do six days

When other cities were attacked nothing spectacular took place.

But when Jericho was about to be attacked certain things took place.

Events that preceded the destruction of Jericho

1) Angelic visitation

2)Priests march around the city seven times

3) Ark of the covenant also goes around the city

4)Two spies sent to spy out Jericho

5)No plunder to be taken from the city

6)People to shout at the sound of the trumpet

7)City cursed by Joshua

Was there a special significance or prophetic meaning behind this siege & subsequent attack?

Comment: Yes Collen. Jesus said "No Jot or title will pass from the law till all is fulfilled". This implies that everything in the law is of prophetic relevance. In Revelations 8-11, seven trumpets were sounded. At the sound of the seventh trumpet, all the cities of the nations fell. And the Kingdoms of the world became Yeshua's. In this passage, at the sound of the seventh Shofar, the wall of Jericho fell and the Kingdoms became Joshua's. Can you see the similarities.

Comment: @user20490,understood

Comment: Jericho = Yareach=it's moon.  In Genesis 1, the moon was the lesser light that ruled over the night. Yahweh and Messiah are always mentioned in connection with the sun but never with the moon. Hence this kingdom of Jericho was a kingdom of the night. A type of the kingdom of darkness.

Comment: It was in Jericho that a babylonish garment was stolen by Achan. So the culture of Babylon (mystery Babylon?) was in the city.

Comment: Joshua's decision to curse the city was wrong. He cursed a part of the promised land. He cursed a portion of the promise. He cursed a part of the Abrahamic inheritance.  It was a very terrible decision by Joshua.

Comment: @user20490 Like the others said, Jericho was a unique demonic stronghold in the Promised Land, an incarnate of the Whore of Babylon. There's no rest with God until He sees this stronghold subjugated and destroyed by His authority (Isaiah 48:22, Ephesians 6:12). His glory is revealed through the defeat of sin.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, every word had a prophetic significance. The histories, the prophets, the law, the psalms had the types, the shadows, the precepts of the new.
As a preview to answering this question we are told in the scripture that Satan is the Prince of this world and that this whole world lieth in wickedness.

1 John 5:19

> 19 And we know that we are of God, and the whole world lieth in
>   wickedness

Satan the Prince of the power of the air rules the darkness of this world and that the people of the world are under his dominion by his Spirit:

Ephesians 2:1,2

> 1 And you hath he quickened, who were dead in trespasses and sins:
>
> 2 Wherein in time past ye walked according to the course of this
>   world, according to the prince of the power of the air, the spirit
>   that now worketh in the children of disobedience:

The works of the world are evil because the evil one is ruling. Jesus says:

John 7:7

> 7 The world cannot hate you; but me it hateth, because I testify of
>   it, that the works thereof are evil.

Jesus came to redeem his people from the present evil world.

Galatians 1:4

> 4 Who gave himself for our sins, that he might deliver us from this
>   present evil world, according to the will of God and our Father:

Right now the kingdom of the world belongs Satan, the beast  but one day, at the sounding of the seventh trumpet they will belong to Christ.

Matthew 4:8,9

8

> Again, the devil taketh him up into an exceeding high mountain, and
>   sheweth him all the kingdoms of the world, and the glory of them;
>
> 9 And saith unto him, All these things will I give thee, if thou wilt
>   fall down and worship me.

Luke 4:5,6

> 5 And the devil, taking him up into an high mountain, shewed unto him
>   all the kingdoms of the world in a moment of time.
>
> 6 And the devil said unto him, All this power will I give thee, and
>   the glory of them: for that is delivered unto me; and to whomsoever I
>   will I give it.

The two scripture above clearly says that the kingdom's of the world belong to Satan. One day they will revert back to the original owner.

In the book of Revelation we read:

Revelation 11:15-19

> 15 And the seventh angel sounded; and there were great voices in
>   heaven, saying, The kingdoms of this world are become the kingdoms of
>   our Lord, and of his Christ; and he shall reign for ever and ever.
>
> 16 And the four and twenty elders, which sat before God on their
>   seats, fell upon their faces, and worshipped God,
>
> 17 Saying, We give thee thanks, O Lord God Almighty, which art, and
>   wast, and art to come; because thou hast taken to thee thy great
>   power, and hast reigned.
>
> 18 And the nations were angry, and thy wrath is come, and the time of
>   the dead, that they should be judged, and that thou shouldest give
>   reward unto thy servants the prophets, and to the saints, and them
>   that fear thy name, small and great; and shouldest destroy them which
>   destroy the earth.
>
> 19 And the temple of God was opened in heaven, and there was seen in
>   his temple the ark of his testament: and there were lightnings, and
>   voices, and thunderings, and an earthquake, and great hail.

The sounding of trumpets in seven different times will finally bring the kingdom to the messiah and the kingdom of Satan will be brought down.

Daniel saw the ending of the gentile kingdom, in types Satan rules over the  sea of the gentiles:

Daniel 2:31-35,44,45

> 31 Thou, O king, sawest, and behold a great image. This great image,
>   whose brightness was excellent, stood before thee; and the form
>   thereof was terrible.
>
> 32 This image's head was of fine gold, his breast and his arms of
>   silver, his belly and his thighs of brass,
>
> 33 His legs of iron, his feet part of iron and part of clay.
>
> 34 Thou sawest till that a stone was cut out without hands, which
>   smote the image upon his feet that were of iron and clay, and brake
>   them to pieces.
>
> 35 Then was the iron, the clay, the brass, the silver, and the gold,
>   broken to pieces together, and became like the chaff of the summer
>   threshingfloors; and the wind carried them away, that no place was
>   found for them: and the stone that smote the image became a great
>   mountain, and filled the whole earth.
>
> 44 And in the days of these kings shall the God of heaven set up a
>   kingdom, which shall never be destroyed: and the kingdom shall not be
>   left to other people, but it shall break in pieces and consume all
>   these kingdoms, and it shall stand for ever.
>
> 45 Forasmuch as thou sawest that the stone was cut out of the mountain
>   without hands, and that it brake in pieces the iron, the brass, the
>   clay, the silver, and the gold; the great God hath made known to the
>   king what shall come to pass hereafter: and the dream is certain, and
>   the interpretation thereof sure.
>
> Daniel 7:13,14,17,18,20-27
>
> 13 I saw in the night visions, and, behold, one like the Son of man
>   came with the clouds of heaven, and came to the Ancient of days, and
>   they brought him near before him.
>
> 14 And there was given him dominion, and glory, and a kingdom, that
>   all people, nations, and languages, should serve him: his dominion is
>   an everlasting dominion, which shall not pass away, and his kingdom
>   that which shall not be destroyed.
>
> 17 These great beasts, which are four, are four kings, which shall
>   arise out of the earth.
>
> 18 But the saints of the most High shall take the kingdom, and possess
>   the kingdom for ever, even for ever and ever.
>
> 20 And of the ten horns that were in his head, and of the other which
>   came up, and before whom three fell; even of that horn that had eyes,
>   and a mouth that spake very great things, whose look was more stout
>   than his fellows.
>
> 21 I beheld, and the same horn made war with the saints, and prevailed
>   against them;
>
> 22 Until the Ancient of days came, and judgment was given to the
>   saints of the most High; and the time came that the saints possessed
>   the kingdom.
>
> 23 Thus he said, The fourth beast shall be the fourth kingdom upon
>   earth, which shall be diverse from all kingdoms, and shall devour the
>   whole earth, and shall tread it down, and break it in pieces.
>
> 24 And the ten horns out of this kingdom are ten kings that shall
>   arise: and another shall rise after them; and he shall be diverse from
>   the first, and he shall subdue three kings.
>
> 25 And he shall speak great words against the most High, and shall
>   wear out the saints of the most High, and think to change times and
>   laws: and they shall be given into his hand until a time and times and
>   the dividing of time.
>
> 26 But the judgment shall sit, and they shall take away his dominion,
>   to consume and to destroy it unto the end.
>
> 27 And the kingdom and dominion, and the greatness of the kingdom
>   under the whole heaven, shall be given to the people of the saints of
>   the most High, whose kingdom is an everlasting kingdom, and all
>   dominions shall serve and obey him.
>    Jericho prefigures the gentile kingdom. Notice in Joshua:

. Joshua 6:2-5

> 2 And the LORD said unto Joshua, See, I have given into thine hand
>   Jericho, and the king thereof, and the mighty men of valour.
>
> 3 And ye shall compass the city, all ye men of war, and go round about
>   the city once. Thus shalt thou do six days.
>
> 4 And seven priests shall bear before the ark seven trumpets of rams'
>   horns: and the seventh day ye shall compass the city seven times, and
>   the priests shall blow with the trumpets.
>
> 5 And it shall come to pass, that when they make a long blast with the
>   ram's horn, and when ye hear the sound of the trumpet, all the people
>   shall shout with a great shout; and the wall of the city shall fall
>   down flat, and the people shall ascend up every man straight before
>   him.

Notice in type, the Bring in of the kingdom of the Messiah, revelation chapter 8:

Revelation 8:2-6

> 2 And I saw the seven angels which stood before God; and to them were
>   given seven trumpets.
>
> 3 And another angel came and stood at the altar, having a golden
>   censer; and there was given unto him much incense, that he should
>   offer it with the prayers of all saints upon the golden altar which
>   was before the throne.
>
> 4 And the smoke of the incense, which came with the prayers of the
>   saints, ascended up before God out of the angel's hand.
>
> 5 And the angel took the censer, and filled it with fire of the altar,
>   and cast it into the earth: and there were voices, and thunderings,
>   and lightnings, and an earthquake.
>
> 6 And the seven angels which had the seven trumpets prepared
>   themselves to sound.

It is at the sounding of the seventh trumpet, the kingdom is taken and great voices are heard from heaven, the seventh  vial is poured for out of the trumpets come forth the vials:

Revelation 16:17-21

> 17 And the seventh angel poured out his vial into the air; and there
>   came a great voice out of the temple of heaven, from the throne,
>   saying, It is done.
>
> 18 And there were voices, and thunders, and lightnings; and there was
>   a great earthquake, such as was not since men were upon the earth, so
>   mighty an earthquake, and so great.
>
> 19 And the great city was divided into three parts, and the cities of
>   the nations fell: and great Babylon came in remembrance before God, to
>   give unto her the cup of the wine of the fierceness of his wrath.
>
> 20 And every island fled away, and the mountains were not found.
>
> 21 And there fell upon men a great hail out of heaven, every stone
>   about the weight of a talent: and men blasphemed God because of the
>   plague of the hail; for the plague thereof was exceeding great.

The kingdom's of the world will fall like the walls of Jericho, like the image in Nebuchadnezzar's dream.

.